# Converting a large txt file into a python dictionary

Tags: python, file, dictionary, key

I got a text file that I need to convert into a python dictionary to work with, the text file looks essentially like this

```
100 Base VG AnyLan
Se basa en el protocolo de prioridad por demanda, se aplica a todo tipo de cableado del tipo ethernet o tokenring.
100BASE-T
Especificación Gigabit Ethernet que emplea UTP Cat5, 5e o 6.
Cada segmento de red puede tener una distancia máxima de 100 m (328 ft) sin un repetidor. También se denomina 801.3ab.
100BASE-TX
Especificación Fast Ethernet de banda base de 100 Mbps que usa dos pares de cableado UTP o STP. Basada en el estándar IEEE 802.3.
100BASE-X
Especificación Ethernet de banda base de 100 Mbps que se refiere a los estándares 100BASE-FX y 100BASE-TX para Fast Ethernet por cableado de cobre o fibra óptica. Basada en el estándar IEEE 802.3.
10BASE-T
Especificación Ethernet de banda base de 10 Mbps que usa dos pares de cables de par trenzado Categoría 3, 4 ó 5. El primer par se usa para recibir datos, y el segundo par se usa para transmitir datos. 10BASE-T, que forma parte de la especificación IEEE 802.3, tiene una limitación de distancia de aproximadamente 100 m (328 ft) por segmento.
16:9
```

And so on. As you can see it consists of one word and its definition.

I've been thinking of ways to iterate through the text file and split the word and definition parts into key : values rather than manually format it one by one given that this file is pretty huge but no luck. What would you do to make this work?

Comment: It seems that the term to define can consist of more than one word (first line) and the definition can consist of one or more lines. I don't see a way to make a simple rule to distinguish term from definition.

Comment: `As you can see it consists of one word and its definition` - am I the only one unable to see that?

Comment: You need a way to distinguish between words and definitions. Newlines would be typical, but not in the sample provided. Is it the case that definition lines always end with `.\n` and word lines always end with `\n`?

Comment: @MichaelRuth Didn't see it like this, still some definitions have more than one line but doing like this and then manually correcting those exceptions should save me some work, it's the best think I can think of so far. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You could apply a *very simple* heuristic to distinguish between "words" and "definitions": every line below 20 characters is a "word", anything else is part of the definition.

Go over each line and if it matches the heuristic, store that as key and put it into the dict. Any other line is appended to the value at the current key.

```py
def parse_file(file):
    with open(file) as f:
        d = {}
        for line in f:
            if len(line) < 20:
                key = line
                d[key] = ''
            else:
                d[key] += line
        return d
```

Note that this is anything but bulletproof and can fail for any reasons with your given input file format.

A different heuristic could be counting the blanks in a given line and anything with less than 5 blanks is considered a "word" (i.e. a key for the dictionary), e.g. `if line.count(' ') < 5`.